# First installation and failed to install grub-pc, how to solve this?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, installation, grub2

How to solve grub setup while first installation?

[image]

(wrong, i choose before to make a new installation, but it was failed and now saying do it manually!! strange behaviour)

[image]

(after installation, boot i get now this blinking cursor)
[image]

What partition do i do? i selected sdb

[image]

Comment: any info about your disk & partitioning?  Are you using a RAID - if so what type?

Comment: @fossfreedom: no RAID

Comment: you look like you are installing on a second disk?  Where is your master boot record pointing to?

Comment: @fossfreedom: LiveUSB is boot device. And i have only one DISK. (where i had previously installed Ubuntu). This is a new installation, where in configuration i mentioned to use entire disk, and it did and it also wrote in the disk.

Comment: @fossfreedom: please see the partition tree, advise plz!!!

Comment: We'd use more info on what went wrong with grub-install. Check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows - since it looks like you've used an Alternate install, follow the steps in **Using the Ubuntu Alternate CD** section and take a photo of the `grub-install` output. You could also try other options, eg [Boot Repair Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason comes to my mind - so called "Virus protection" present in some BIOSes. This feature basically locks down MBR from overwriting.

If you've never changed bootloader on this PC before, look into the CMOS Setup whether this feature isn't enabled (it may be called otherwise than "virus protection" - look for keywords: lock, boot, MBR or Master Boot Record and check out the manual for your motherboard).

Comment: No its enabled. (i can even use other live media to change and write)

Comment: So it isn't enabled (note that changing MBR is a different part of your disk, the fact you can reformat your disk doesn't mean you can rewrite MBR - just double check).

Comment: i have still that black screen after boot with cursor blinking every few times i installed freshly. Should i have to use this or what? http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Comment: Uh... Have you solved the problem?

Comment: see solution: http://askubuntu.com/questions/73345/how-to-fix-my-mbr-while-installing-random-ubuntu-my-mbr-is-not-getting-overwrit/73358#73358